# Should it be allowed to apply classical logic to set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, philosophy

It is well known, that the generalized continuum hypothesis isn't provable from the standard axiom system ZFC.

GCH (generalized continuum hypothesis). For every infinite set A, there isn't a set M such that |A| < |M| < |P(A)| (where P(A) denotes the power set of A).

Using classical logic, one can deduce the following:

> GCH is either true or false.

But for me this statement does not make any sense because GCH is not true nor false, just because the concept of "set" is too ambiguous, in other words: the statement does not make any sense because "GCH is either true or false" isn't a proposition: it has no truth value.

How is one able to justify that one can say statements like

> GCH is either true or false.

although this makes no sense for a non-platonist?

Comment: In every specific model of set theory, it's either true or false.

Answer (score 3):

One does not have to justify any philosophical statement in mathematics. Because philosophical statements represent some overarching drive as to where to move forward in mathematics.

You believe that something should be true, or something should be provable, means that you want to prove that this is the case. It is a light in the darkness which lies beyond the map. Where new research comes from.

But it is just a personal belief based on what you've seen so far, what you've proved, and how it all makes sense *to you, in your mind*.

What you said, however, is a bit misleading. Classical logic tells us that in a *given model of $\sf ZFC$* a statement is either true or false, not to mention that if something is not provable does not mean that it is neither true nor false. It just means that you can't prove, from your current assumption which one it is. So if you are a Platonist, and you believe there is a true model of $\sf ZFC$, it just means that you have to decide for yourself - by the evidence that you see in mathematics - whether or not $\sf GCH$ *should* be true or false.

So if a Platonist (you or otherwise) feels that $\sf GCH$ is true, they might work towards formulating axioms that imply $\sf GCH$ (like Ultimate-L of Woodin) and towards pushing others into taking these axioms as canon. Or they might work to show that $\lnot\sf GCH$ has various undesirable consequences.

But at no point a Platonist is going to force you to accept an axiom. At best, they might argue that you're missing some bigger picture, or that all signs point at some direction. And if you're not a Platonist, like me for example, then you can just take that with a grain of salt, and focus on the mathematics instead.

In any case, without specifying a specific model there is no mathematical meaning to the statement "$\sf GCH$ is true". In some cases, like $\sf PA$, there is a standard model and "true" is a shorthand for "true in the standard model". But $\sf ZFC$ does not have this luxury (for better or worse) of ***a*** unique, well-specified standard model.

Comment: Your answer is completely fine -- for you -- but it does not help me. I ask the question: "How to justify ...", your answer: "One has not to justify ..." But I think one has to justify this, and I want a justification as an answer.

Comment: If your question is "What can convince me?" then it is impossible to answer. Nobody but you knows that. You want some justification, but you don't know what it is. Why would *anyone* know what it is?

Comment: If your question is "Why do some Platonists believe GCH is true?" then you should *ask* that question. Not some vague question like this one.

Comment: @euerrrrrrr You seem to think that set theory describes a unique universe of sets, somehow. This is not what set theory is. Does group theory have a unique model? If not, then the statement "$G$ is Abelian" is also a contradiction to classical logic, as it might or might not hold....

Comment: @Henno: Thus proving *once and for all* that all mathematics is a huge scam to use public and private funding to stall the development of free, renewable and clean energy source!!!!11 :-)

Answer (score 0):

The viewpoint that the continuum hypothesis contains an intrinsic ambiguity ("is inherently vague") is a legitimate one, and has been pursued by the distinguished logician Sol Feferman; see e.g.,

Feferman, Solomon; Friedman, Harvey M.; Maddy, Penelope; Steel, John R.
Does mathematics need new axioms? 
Bull. Symbolic Logic  6  (2000),  no. 4, 401–446

where this viewpoint is developed in full.  Feferman's alternative is the predicative viewpoint inspired by Hermann Weyl.